# Magenta line will not go away on my monitor

Tags: display, fedora, resolution

I recently built my own computer, and I was excited to finally put it all together yesterday and get it running. However, I have noticed an annoying issue on my monitor, and I don't know if it's a hardware- or software-oriented problem.

There is a random magenta line on the far left of my monitor, right on the border of the screen. It seems that the system either is unable to see the full screen size, or there is another issue at play.

Interestingly enough, I do not notice it at the motherboard BIOS screen or the kernel selection screen, but only once my operating system has booted does it appear.

My monitor is a [Samsung S24D300H 60Hz 24.0" Monitor](http://pcpartpicker.com/part/samsung-monitor-s24d300h) and I am running Fedora 20 as my operating system.

Is there any way I can diagnose where this issue is coming from and how I can fix it? Any help would be appreciated, and if more information is needed, please just ask.

Comment: How is your computer connected to the monitor? what resolution are you running it at?

Comment: @Arthur I am connecting it via HDMI. I believe the resolution is 1980, but I will have to confirm that later when I am back in front of the computer.

Comment: Try the monitor on another computer. If it still does it there, then it's an issue with the monitor.  Try a different cable. If it fixes it, then it's a problem with your cable. etc...

Comment: In addition, I would try changing the resolution. If it works on one resolution and not another, that could imply a problem with the monitor.

Comment: @Arthur: I tried changing the resolution to a wide range of different options, but with no luck. On each one I tried, the magenta line was still there, and about the same size too.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: Unfortunately, I do not have any other monitors available to test with. However, when I was testing my build at another location, I had it hooked up to a TV monitor. The window of the operating system didn't fit on the TV screen, so I'm not sure if there was a magenta line there or not. I'm wondering if it might be my HDMI cable, as it was an old one I had lying around that I ordered for 5¢ on Amazon from Thailand. :P